# What is the speed of the boy in still water?

Tags: algebra-precalculus

In a fixed time, a boy swims double the distance along the current
that he swims against the current. If the speed of the current is 3 kmph then what is the speed of the boy in still water?

A) the speed of the current; y = 3 kmph

the speed of the current; X = ?

time = constant

Downstream speed; X + 3

Upstream speed; X – 3

How to proceed from here?

Comment: You have got the time ,speed and distance. Try plugging them into the formula of speed and manipulate the equation.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In an hour,

$$v+3=2(v-3)$$ so that $v=9$ km/h.

Answer (score 0):

We have the relationship $$\text{distance}=\text{speed}\times\text{time}.$$

Going downstream, we have $d_1=s_1t_1$.  Let $s_1=x+3$ represent the downstream speed and we have $d_1=(x+3)t_1$.
Going upstream, we have $d_2=s_2t_2$.  Let $s_2=x-3$ represent the upstream speed and we have $d_2=(x-3)t_2$.

Since $t_1=t_2$ and $d_1=2d_2$, we have $2d_2=x+3$ and $d_2=x-3$.  Using substitution, we have $$2(x-3)=x+3\implies x=9$$
by inspection.

Answer (score 0):

I've always found it helpful using as many variables as possible. My personal preference has always been using "physics" style variables (as they're much more descriptive that "algebra" style ones).
$$\begin{align}
D_{\text{with the current}} &= 2D_{\text{against the current}}\\
\frac{D_{\text{with the current}}}{T} &= \frac{2D_{\text{against the current}}}{T}\\
V_{\text{with the current}} &= 2V_{\text{against the current}}\\
V_{\text{boy}} + V_{\text{current}} &= 2(V_{\text{boy}} - V_{\text{current}})\\
V_{\text{boy}} + 3 &= 2(V_{\text{boy}} - 3)\\
V_{\text{boy}} + 3 &= 2V_{\text{boy}} - 6\\
\dots
\end{align}$$